# Strange behavior of Xcode Build Products Path under Build Locations

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode4

I've been looking for an answer but I couldn't find so I'm posting the question here.

Every Project I created under Xcode4 gets the exactly the same "Build Products Path" under the project or target settings - Build Locations

I wonder if this is because I did something back in Xcode 3 and somehow permanently set the value ?

I have uninstall completely and re-install from scratch and still the same thing.

I just created 3 brand new ios projects (windows based) under the xcode4 and those all have the exactly same value for Build Products Path...  in my case, it's always pointing to

/Users/RebeccaKennedy/Documents/Projects/iPhone/tmp

every time!  every project... this is getting really annoying...

Answer (score 8):

1. Close all your projects in Xcode, but leave Xcode open
2. Open up ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
3. Find the key: IDEApplicationwideBuildSettings
4. Delete the two items in that key
5. Save, restart Xcode

be careful w/ step two.  the .dt. is for Xcode 4. without the dt is for Xcode 3.

This is almost certainly the result of Xcode migrating old preferences to 4 from 3.

Comment: This seems to work too, "/usr/lib/exec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist" and then give the command "Delete IDEApplicationwideBuildSettings" followed by "Save" and "Exit"

Answer (score 5):

You haven't said what you've tried...but check this setting in Xcode Preferences.

[image: Locations]

I assume you've check these two locations (search for tmp)?

[image: test - test.xcodeproj]

Comment: I tried that before and I tried again.  It is exactly set as what you posted.  I didn't change anything in there nor it was different than what you posted..

new projects still getting created with the value "/Users/RebeccaKennedy/Documents/Projects/iPhone/tmp"

Comment: You might not have fixed Becky's problem, but you fixed mine!  I need the projects to build in folders relative to their root for a continuous integration server, but Xcode 4 was ignoring the Build Products Path set in the target build settings and putting everything in the derived data location.

Comment: @Joe IBanez - Excellent. Glad to hear it! Cheers