# Xcode build products folder won't change to Unique

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

I don't recall having this problem before I migrated to my Retina MacBook Pro, but since doing so, my projects have insisted on loading in the "old" development location.   In years past, before XCode 4, we put all our products in `/Development/Products`.   And, after migrating to the new MacBook Pro, they're going back there again.   I can use 4.3 or newer and see the same problem with both, so I'm assuming it's some kind of configurable that's at work here.

Of course, the first thing I did was verify that the Preferences/Locations was set to Build Location = Unique.   I confirmed this both in the GUI and by popping open the .plist to check the value of `IDEBuildLocationStyle` and it was set to Unique.

I tried removing my existing configuration files (everthing in `~/Library/Preferences/` named *Xcode*) and that succeeded in changing the behavior to putting the output in the `build` directory of the project itself (really not helpful in my world as I have complex multi-project workspaces).  Quitting and checking the settings, they were set for `IDEBuildLocationStyle`=`Unique.`

So, I copied the working configuration from another machine I had to this one.   Since it too had previously had the `/Development/Products` destination, but had subsequently been moved to the Unique build style, I expected that to work.   It did not.   It instead returned the output to `/Development/Products`.

Thinking it might be something with my Xcode install, I created a new user and built from the same source tree (not a duplicate, not a copy, the exact same files).   In this case, the output went to the right place (unique subdirectory of the Derived Products for that user).    So, I blew away the `~/Preferences/*Xcode*` again and copied in the preferences from the new user.   Unfortunately, this took us back to the same behavior that the uninitialized configuration had, which is to say building in the build directory of the project itself.

I restored to my backup configuration files, and now I'm back to working at `/Development/Products`, but this isn't a good long term solution.

When checking the script output for a test script, I can clearly see that somebody is setting `SYMROOT` to `/Development/Products` in the case of the older config, and `build` in the case of the default configuration file.

Clearly there's something here on this system that's influencing the configuration, but I cannot figure out what it is.    Any assistance would be highly appreciated!

Also - When I try to use option-Clean to enable Clean Build Folder, it is never enabled, which makes a certain kind of sense, but I thought it might be another data point.

I tried the solution in [Strange behavior of Xcode Build Products Path under Build Locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599587/strange-behavior-of-xcode-build-products-path-under-build-locations) and that had the same result as deleting the preferences: build products as children of the project directory.

Has anyone else seen such a problem?   Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a very long time of suffering through this on my laptop, I was finally able to track down the problem.

Inside of:

```
project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/<user>.xcuserdatad/
```

there is a `WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings` file.

It contained a key `BuildLocationStyle`, which was set to `UseTargetSettings`.

Deleting the file and thus resetting this value allowed me to get both the `Clean Build Folder...` working and to get my project building correctly.

Hopefully this will help somebody else.

Comment: Just ran into this myself, and found that this is set by File > Project Settings or File > Workspace Settings.